# Unzip template-template parameter from type bundle

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-templates

How to fix the `using` line?

test_temp.cpp:

```
#include <memory>
template <typename A, typename B, template<typename> class C>
class X {};

template <typename A1, typename B1, template<typename> class C1>
class Type_bundle {
public:
    typedef A1 A;
    typedef B1 B;
    template<typename T> using C = C1<T>;
};

template <typename T_b>
using X_b = X<typename T_b::A, typename T_b::B, typename T_b::template C>;


int main() {
    typedef Type_bundle<int,float,std::allocator> Ttb;
    X_b<Ttb> x;
}
```

Error from clang++

```
test_temp.cpp:14:63: error: expected an identifier or template-id after '::'
using X_b = X<typename T_b::A, typename T_b::B, typename T_b::template C>;
                                                         ~~~~~^
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
template <typename T_b>
using X_b = X<typename T_b::A, typename T_b::B, typename T_b::template C>;
//                                              ~~~~~~~~~
```

That suggests that what follows will be the name of a type. But `T_b::template C` isn't a type, it's a template, so this construct isn't valid. You'd use that construct if you went on to pass parameters into `C`, like `typename T_b::template C<D>`. There, both `typename` and `template` are necessary.

What you want is just:

```
template <typename T_b>
using X_b = X<typename T_b::A, typename T_b::B, T_b::template C>;
```

No `typename`.

Answer (score -1):

This compiles:

```
#include <memory>
template <typename A, typename B, template<typename> class C>
class X {};

template <typename A1, typename B1, template<typename> class C1>
class Type_bundle {
public:
    typedef A1 A;
    typedef B1 B;
    template<typename T> using C = C1<T>;
};

template <typename T_b>
using X_b = X<typename T_b::A, typename T_b::B, 
              T_b::template C >;
int main() {
    typedef Type_bundle<int,float,std::allocator> Ttb;
    X_b<Ttb> x;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this works. But after trying different combinations of `typename T`, `template` etc. I get this. If the template gets more complex, this kind of brute force search is just so much fun.